# Python Attribute Error 'Map' object has no attribute 'cells'

Tags: java, python

I'm trying to translate a java code into Python, but I'm encountering an attribute not found error.

Here's the java code that works:

Map.java

```
public class Map {
  private Cell[][] cells;

  public Map() {
    this.cells = new Cell[7][7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        this.cells[i][j] = new Cell();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Cell.java

```
public class Cell {
  private Object occupiedObject;

  public Cell() {
    this.occupiedObject = null;
  }
}
```

Here's my Python code that has the error:

Map.py

```
from Cell import Cell

class Map():
     def __init__(self):
          for i in range(7):
               for j in range(7):
                    self.cells[i][j] = Cell()
```

Cell.py

```
class Cell():
     def __init__(self):
          self.occupiedObject = None
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like that:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.occupied_object = None

class Map:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cells = [[Cell() for x in range(7)] for y in range(7)]
```